# Displaying data from database into fullcalendar through servlet - No events listed

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, netbeans, fullcalendar

This is the first time I've ever worked with .jsp and Netbeans. I'm trying to create a system utilizing fullcalendar where a user can select the month/year pair and display who is on leave on what day in the selected month. Basically, instead of listing events, it will list absent staff names. I'll refer to the names as events.

The problem here is that the calendar is not displaying any events. I've followed [this tutorial](https://mohittare.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/using-fullcalendarwithjava/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698271/how-to-use-fullcalendar-js-that-it-picks-data-from-database-and-display-data-in) (which refers to the tutorial I've linked) but I can't seem to get it working. The calendar is there, but there's no event. I can add an event manually either trough clicking the calendar or editing the array inside the .jsp, but I want it to generate the events from the database.

This is my code:

main.jsp

```
<form name="choose" method="POST">
<table class="centerTable">
<tr>
    <td>Month</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <select name="month" style="width:130px" required>
    <option value="">Select a month:</option>
    <option value="${01}" ${param.month == 01 ? 'selected' : ''}>January</option>
    <option value="${02}" ${param.month == 02 ? 'selected' : ''}>February</option>
    <option value="${03}" ${param.month == 03 ? 'selected' : ''}>March</option>
    <option value="${04}" ${param.month == 04 ? 'selected' : ''}>April</option>
    <option value="${05}" ${param.month == 05 ? 'selected' : ''}>May</option>
    <option value="${06}" ${param.month == 06 ? 'selected' : ''}>June</option>
    <option value="${07}" ${param.month == 07 ? 'selected' : ''}>July</option>
    <option value="${08}" ${param.month == 08 ? 'selected' : ''}>August</option>
    <option value="${09}" ${param.month == 09 ? 'selected' : ''}>September</option>
    <option value="${10}" ${param.month == 10 ? 'selected' : ''}>October</option>
    <option value="${11}" ${param.month == 11 ? 'selected' : ''}>November</option>
    <option value="${12}" ${param.month == 12 ? 'selected' : ''}>December</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Year</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
    <select name="year" style="width:130px" required>
    <option value="">Select a year:</option>
    <option value="${2016}" ${param.year == '2016' ? 'selected' : ''}>2016</option>
    <option value="${2015}" ${param.year == '2015' ? 'selected' : ''}>2015</option>
    <option value="${2014}" ${param.year == '2014' ? 'selected' : ''}>2014</option>
    <option value="${2013}" ${param.year == '2013' ? 'selected' : ''}>2013</option>
    <option value="${2012}" ${param.year == '2012' ? 'selected' : ''}>2012</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan=3 align=center>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onChange="submit();return false;"> 
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<script>
var y = "${param.year}";
var m = "${param.month}";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');

        var eventData;
        if (title) {
            eventData = {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end
                };
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        events: "/Leave/KServlet"
    });
    if (y === "" || m === "")
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('today');
    else
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', (y+'-'+m));
});
</script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

KServlet.java

```
public class KServlet extends HttpServlet
{ 
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        List l = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Connection con = null;

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:\\Users\\Acer\\Desktop\\livedb?username=username&password=password");

            int month, year;
            if (request.getParameter("month").equals(""))
                month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            else
                month = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("month"));

            if (request.getParameter("year").equals(""))
                year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            else
                year = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("year"));

            Statement stmt = null;
            String query = "select PERSON_NAME, TYPE_CODE, FROM_DATE, TO_DATE " +
                           "from LV_INFO_VIEW " +
                           "where YEAR(FROM_DATE) = " + year + " and MONTH(FROM_DATE) = " + month;

            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                CalendarDTO c = new CalendarDTO();
                c.setTitle(rs.getString("PERSON_NAME"));
                c.setStart(rs.getString("FROM_DATE"));
                c.setEnd(rs.getString("TO_DATE"));

                String t = rs.getString("TYPE_CODE");

                if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("ANNUAL") || t.equalsIgnoreCase("AL - CT"))
                {
                    c.setColor("green");
                    c.setTextColor("white");
                }
                else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("MEDICAL") || t.equalsIgnoreCase("ML-CT"))
                {
                    c.setColor("red");
                    c.setTextColor("white");
                }
                else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("MARRIAGE"))
                {
                    c.setColor("#ff6699");
                    c.setTextColor("black");
                }
                else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("MATERNITY") || t.equalsIgnoreCase("PATERNITY"))
                {
                    c.setColor("#b2e7d3");
                    c.setTextColor("black");
                }
                else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("UNPAID"))
                {
                    c.setColor("blue");
                    c.setTextColor("white");
                }
                else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("COMPASSIONATE") || t.equalsIgnoreCase("DOF"))
                {
                    c.setColor("black");
                    c.setTextColor("white");
                }
                else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("REPLACEMENT"))
                {
                    c.setColor("#720045");
                    c.setTextColor("white");
                }
                else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("HOSPITAL") || t.equalsIgnoreCase("SICK"))
                {
                    c.setColor("#7a0000");
                    c.setTextColor("white");
                }
                else if (t.equalsIgnoreCase("EMERGENCY"))
                {
                    c.setColor("yellow");
                    c.setTextColor("black");
                }
                else
                {
                    c.setColor("#ffd4b1");
                    c.setTextColor("black");
                }

                l.add(c);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) { Logger.getLogger(KServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); }

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(new Gson().toJson(l));
    }
}
```

There's also CalendarDTO class. It contains title, start, end, color, and textColor. All variables are Strings and have respective setters & getters.

The servlet is properly mapped in web.xml and Netbeans doesn't output any errors.

However, from Chrome console I can see that KServlet returned a blank page with only '[]'. My guess it that I messed up something in the servlet, but I'm not sure what.

I'm really thankful to anyone who can help.

Comment: Did you check the bowser console in the network tab for ajax call? Also put some breakpoints at the `KServlet.java`

Comment: I've checked it, Kservlet returns a page with only '[]'. I'm not sure where to put breakpoints so I just selected 'Any XHR'.

Comment: Check your sql first with params

Comment: Put breakpoints at `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)` and `l.add(c)`. Also start server in debug mode.

Comment: @hurricane As far I can see, there's nothing wrong with the SQL. I even tried with a simple statement like "select PERSON_NAME from LV_INFO_VIEW where FROM_DATE = '2015-04-10'" and Netbeans outputs the result without fault in its database manager but the serlvet still returns a blank list '[]'.

Comment: @Arvind I've placed the breakpoints in Netbeans. At first NB did notify me on a breakpoint, but after I restarted the IDE and changed a few lines (SQL statement, predefined month & year) it no longer does that.

Comment: Can you sysout "new Gson().toJson(l)" ? i think this method is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Arvind and hurricane, I managed to get it working now. It was the arrangement of javascript import and unsuitable datatype (String instead of int) in addition to bad SQL statement that causes the trouble.

I've edited my script in case someone wants to use it as a guide